# How quickly can a Thylean Centaur climb?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, racial-traits, stacking, centaur

I'm playing the Thylean Centaur race (from the third-party *Odyssey of the Dragonlords* module), which has the following trait:

> ***Quadrapedal Stride.*** Climbing or maneuvering in tight spaces is considered difficult terrain for you.

Since climbing (unless you have a climbing speed) means you move at half speed, would this ability stack with that rule, making it so I move at 1/4th of my speed?

Comment: Side note: you should also get clarity on what exactly "maneuvering in tight spaces" means. Since there are already rules for squeezing into tight spaces. Alternatively, since this is a homebrew race, you might want to just replace this feature with the equivalent one from one of the officially published quadruped races, which should be better playtested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You move at one-third speed.

The rules for [climbing, swimming, and crawling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#ClimbingSwimmingandCrawling) state:

> Each foot of movement costs 1 extra foot (*2 extra feet in difficult terrain*) when you’re climbing, swimming, or crawling.

Climbing in difficult terrain costs two extra feet of movement, so each foot you climb costs three feet of movement: one-third speed. So it’s worse than half speed, but not quite as bad as the one-fourth speed you originally thought.